# How do I print elements of a 2D matrix in C using base address?

Tags: c, matrix

I've written a code that takes elements from the user for a 2-d matrix and then prints using the base address of matrix.
for simplicity i've omitted the inputting part .
Here's the code that I've tried:-

```
 main()
 {
  int mat[50][50],i, j, r, c, *p;
   p = &mat[0][0];

   <------skip the input---->

 for(i = 0; i < r; i++) /* print the matrix*/
   {
      for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
      {
         printf("%d\t", *((p + i) + j));
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
}


Input: 
1
2
3
4

Output:
1   2
2   0
```

looks like my code is wrong. plz help.Really confused!!!

Comment: maybe you need the basic knowledge between array ant pointers. *(*(p +i) + j). ----- Oh, sorry im wrong.

Comment: ^ Don't pay attention to this, it's wrong.

Comment: To access the next row of the matrix, you need to add the stride (i.e. 50 elements per row) which you multiply by the row index.  So you would have `*(p + i * 50 + j)`

Comment: Why do you even want to use the base pointer to print that...

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you want to print is `p[i][j]` which is equivalent to *(p + (i*rowNum) + j). This can be as shown below.

```
printf("%d\t", *(p + (c  *  i) + j);
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you want to do it with pointers ?
Here is a simpler solution:

```
int matrix[SIZE][SIZE] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };

for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", matrix[row][col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: OP stated very clearly the ways he wants to do it. Your way is not the desired way.